# Sorting Random Numbers in my array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have made an array in python that generates 20 random numbers 50-100. I want to know how to sort the numbers in my array. I am in 8th grade and this is for my computing class. Can this even be done? My teacher mentioned some kind of sorting algorithm, but told me not to use sort(). I am using python. Thanks
this is what i have so far

```
from random import*
array = range(20)
for i in range(20):
    array[i] = randint(50, 100)
print array
```

Comment: yes it is possible; look at "insertion sort" or "bubble sort". They seem pretty easy.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: There is lots of information on sorting algorithms.  [Bubble Sort](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) is one of the most simple sorting algorithms, and one I would recommend starting with.

Comment: If you just want to get your homework done, googling for "python sorting" should be easy enough. If you really want to learn something from this, do NOT follow any links posted, but try to think about the problem on your own. Make 20-30 paper cards with numbers and try to sort them on your desk first. Make notes on how you compare and move cards. Try to implement this logic in python. Get back to us when you've got any specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's an homework I won't give you the solution, but a starting point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm where you can find an introduction to sorting algorithms!
Just choose one and try to implement it! Then if you do something wrong you can ask for help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has posted excellent answers. I want to point you to [this page](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/), because it has a set of good animations for various different sorting algorithms.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done and there are a number of ways to do it, you need to implement your own sorting algorithm, examples of which are very easy to come accross.

I will point you towards a python implementation of one of these algorithms with excellent explanation but i strongly suggest you read up on this sort of stuff as it is the foundation of computer science imho.

go [here](http://hetland.org/coding/python/quicksort.html) for a python quicksort program.. but please do the work around it.

Also i have to reccommend [Introduction to Algorithms by thomas h cormen](http://goo.gl/9TiIA) which is an awesome book and took me through a lot of stuff, and I still look at it to this day. A word of warning on this book.. it is not a light read.

If you find all this a bit heavy I found a [youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P00xJgWzz2c) which goes through bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

For educational purposes, this should be a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort  It's not a very good sorting algorithm, but once you understand the principles you can move on to more advanced sorting algorithms (which you will probably learn in class eventually).

Essentially, you compare every element to the next one, and swap them if they are out of order.  Continue doing this until your array is sorted.  Good luck!